# I can't open port 7777 in Azure

Tags: azure

Idk why ports don't working in Microsoft Azure.

I added all : https://i.stack.imgur.com/9S1z6.png

And here show: https://i.stack.imgur.com/J6AZV.png

Please help.

Comment: Try rebooting the VM.

Comment: Still not working.

Answer (score 0):

Please also ensure that you have opened 7777 port in your OS firewall.